# Selenium / Python function logging (start / end)

Tags: python, selenium

I have been trying to practice selenium using Instagram. Im trying to find a way other than print() to log that the function is running, if possible would like to know the how long it took to complete as well.

currently using something like this -

```
def login(self):

    print("login started")
    login_url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"

    self.driver.get(login_url)
    sleep(2)

    email_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
    password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')

    email_input.send_keys(INSTA_EMAIL)
    password_input.send_keys(INSTA_PASS)

    sleep(2)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print("login successful")
```

Would appreciate if you could point me to any functions / documentations which can help to show when a function started and end. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar for my functions recently. Maybe this could help you, you could add this :

```
def logging_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # get start time
        start_time = time()
        # get current function name 
        print(f"{function.__name__} function started")
        # calling the function
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        # get the end time
        end_time = time()
        print(f"{function.__name__} function completed, run speed: {end_time - start_time} s")
    return wrapper
```

and use it like this :

```
@logging_decorator
def login(self):

    login_url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"

    self.driver.get(login_url)
    sleep(2)

        email_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
        password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')

        email_input.send_keys(INSTA_EMAIL)
        password_input.send_keys(INSTA_PASS)

        sleep(2)
        password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Expected output :

```
login function started
login function completed, run speed:XXs
```

You can read more on this here :
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator